# Google Cloud Build, Cloud Run, Cloud SQL Prisma Migration

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-sql, prisma, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am trying to get a Google Cloud Build pipeline running with a Node.js application that is using Google Cloud Build, Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) and Prisma for the ORM.  I have started with the default `yaml` provided by GCP Cloud Build when clicking on the `Setup Continuous Integration` button on the Cloud Run UI view for an existing application.  The part that is missing is the prisma migrations for the Cloud SQL instance.

```yaml
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '-t'
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - .
      - '-f'
      - api/Dockerfile
    id: Build
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
    id: Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - '--platform=managed'
      - '--image=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID,$_LABELS
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--quiet'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud
images:
  - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
tags:
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run-managed
  - api
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue by using the following Cloud Build yaml.  This is hosted within my `git` repo, so any code changes are tracked.  I selected the `Repository` as the source and added the location of the `cloudbuild.yaml` file in my repo rather than the `inline` option in the Google Cloud Build trigger.  This solution should work as long as there aren't any breaking changes from the previous API version to the new version (this won't work for a short period of time until the new application code has all the traffic running to it if you, for example, rename a field in the database that the old application code relies on).  The way to manage this is not to make breaking changes and migrate the data from the old column to the new column before removing the old column.  Another option is to schedule downtime for DB maintenance.

Keep in mine that there is a race condition when the database migrations run, but the previous version of the code is still accepting traffic before the cut over and that people using the application will potentially receive 500 errors.

This is the updated `cloudbuild.yaml` with the Prisma migration step (note: This also uses Google Cloud Secret Manager for the DB):

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'node:$_NODE_VERSION'
    entrypoint: 'yarn'
    id: yarn-install
    args: ['install']
    waitFor: ["-"]

  - id: migrate
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn
    env:
      - NODE_ENV=$_NODE_ENV
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
        wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
        chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
        ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=$$_DB_HOST=tcp:$$_DB_PORT & sleep 3
        export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://$$_DB_USER:$$_DB_PASS@localhost/$$_DB_NAME?schema=public
        yarn workspace api run migrate
    secretEnv: ['_DB_USER', '_DB_PASS',  '_DB_HOST', '_DB_NAME', '_DB_PORT']
    timeout: "1200s"
    waitFor: ["yarn-install"]

  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '-t'
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - .
      - '-f'
      - api/Dockerfile
    id: Build
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
    id: Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - '--platform=managed'
      - '--image=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID,$_LABELS
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--quiet'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud
images:
  - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/DB_NAME/versions/latest
    env: '_DB_NAME'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/DB_PASS/versions/latest
    env: '_DB_PASS'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/DB_PORT/versions/latest
    env: '_DB_PORT'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/DB_USER/versions/latest
    env: '_DB_USER'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/DB_HOST/versions/latest
    env: '_DB_HOST'

tags:
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run-managed
  - api
```

Comment: Is this cloudbuild in addition to the one on top?  Because in this one you're not building, pushing or deploying does this code go below the existing one you put in the question?

Comment: @JamesDaly I wrote this up awhile ago, but I believe if you scroll down in look at the entire yaml it is `building`, `pushing` and `deploying`.  At least the steps named in there are using the gcr.io names that are intended to help with those parts.

Comment: Why the first step of yarn install? Why is that needed?
also   why do this in migrate      
export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://$$_DB_USER:$$_DB_PASS@localhost/$$_DB_NAME?schema=public
yarn workspace api run migrate
what does that script do? would that be equivalent of running an npm script

Comment: Also I posted a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76847376/running-npx-prisma-migrate-inside-cloud-build-using-cloud-sql-and-cloud-run-mys

Comment: @JamesDaly yes, yarn does a similar job as npm.  You can learn about it here https://yarnpkg.com.  As far as that particular migration command, that is a prism database migration script.  Primsa is a DB ORM https://www.prisma.io

Comment: thank you again for this answer this helped me on my journey which almost took two weeks to resolve but I finally figured out after implementing this that for my sql on prisma I had to add ?socket=/cloudsql/{connectionname} to my databbase url in cloud run

Comment: Good to hear it's working for you now!